# Returning True or False in a HTTPRequest from c# to a php file on the server

Tags: c#, php, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httprequest

I am creating a app which shows news that is placed in a database on a external server. The app loads a JSON that gets created on that server and fills it's listview with it. I am creating the app in c# (Xamarin Forms, Cross platform).

Right now I can download the JSON from the server and the list gets filled. Perfect.

But now I want to do a check if there is new news. And if there is, the check returns true and then the JSON gets downloaded again.

So I was thinking of creating a PHP file which takes an argument through a get request. It sends the timestamp of the last time a JSON was requested with it: "www.example.com/test.php?timestamp=82436594365"

So now, in the PHP script I retrieve this timestamp. I know how to do that. But now I want to do the DB check in the php script and then send true or false back to the app.

How do I achieve this? I tried searching on Google but I need some more explanation. I have no idea how this part works.

I hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with your Xamarin part, so why putting Xamarin tags?

Comment: It does, I need to get this true/false inside my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pseudo-code

```
var count = select count(stories) where timestamp > last_timestamp;

if (count > 0) 
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Comment: So if you use return in php that will be the value that is received in my app which does the httprequest?

How do I actually receive this on my app side?

Comment: you can just return true as the body of the response, or you can wrap it in json if that's easier for you to deal with.  I'm not a PHP expert - you'll need to do some research to turn that into valid PHP code.